# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant get my update button to work, my SQL syntax isnt targeting the datebase properly, this is the syntax im using

```
$sql = ("UPDATE crud SET name='$name', last='$last', email='$email', birthday='$birthday' WHERE id=$id") or
    die($mysqli->error);
```

i tried using different syntaxs but it doesnt update the database

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Using PHP and a Database</title>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .person {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid darkgray;
      background-color: lightyellow;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .person .photo {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

   <form action="people-list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

       <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" /> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    </p>

         <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">birthday</label>
        <input type="text" name="birthday" value="<?php echo $birthday; ?>" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="save">save</button>   

                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="savechange">Save Changes</button>   

</form> 



  <h1>Using PHP and a Database</h1>

  <p>Here is a list of all the records in our people table:</p>

  <?php    

$id = 0;



    // first, set general PHP error reporting and mysqli error reporting
  // in order to be sure we will see every error in the script
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

  // Connect to our MySQL server
  $host = "localhost";
  $user_id = "crud";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "crud";
  $mysqli = new mysqli(
    $host, $user_id, $password, $database
  );

  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" 
      . $mysqli->connect_errno 
      . ") " 
      . $mysqli->connect_error
    ;
  }
  echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

  // Create the SQL command


if (isset($_POST['save'])) 
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$last = $_POST['last'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];  

$sql = "INSERT INTO crud (name, last, email, birthday)
VALUES ('$name', '$last', '$email', '$birthday')"; 

}


if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
{
$id = $_GET['delete'];    
$sql = ("DELETE FROM crud WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error()); 


}


 if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];


    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM crud WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error());
     if ($results){
         $row = $results->fetch_array();
         $name = $row['name'];
         $last = $row['last'];
         $email = $row['email'];
         $birthday = $row['birthday'];
     }

 }



if(isset($_POST['savechange'])) {
       $id = $_POST['id'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $last = $_POST['last'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

    $sql = ("UPDATE crud SET name='$name', last='$last', email='$email', birthday='$birthday' WHERE id=$id") or
        die($mysqli->error);





    $_SESSION['MSG_TYPE'] = "WARNING";

}              

  //     $sql = ("UPDATE crud SET (name, last, email, birthday) VALUES ('$name', '$last', '$email', '$birthday') WHERE id=$id");        
//if (isset($_GET['update'])) 
//{
//$id = $_GET['update'];    
//$sql = ("SELECT FROM crud WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error()); 


//}                   


    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}



$sql = "SELECT * FROM crud";
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // First parameter is just return of "mysqli_connect()" function
echo "<br>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { // Important line !!! Check summary get row on array ..
      echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";    
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['birthday'] . "</td>";

         echo "<td><a href='people-list.php?delete=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></td>";
         echo "<td><a href='people-list.php?edit=".$row['id']."'>update</a></td>";


        //"htmlspecialchars()" function. 

     echo "</tr>";
}


    $mysqli->close();



    ?>

</body>
</html>


sql

-- PHP Version: 7.2.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `crud`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `crud`
--

CREATE TABLE `crud` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `crud`
--

INSERT INTO `crud` (`id`, `name`, `last`, `email`, `birthday`) VALUES
(21, '', '', '', ''),
(22, '', '', '', ''),
(23, 'hhh', 'hhh', 'hh', 'jjj'),
(26, 'hi', 'ff', 'ff', 'dd'),
(27, '111', '222', '222', '222'),
(28, 'ddd', 'sss', 'sss', 'ddd'),
(29, 'hhh', 'hhh', 'hhh', 'hhh'),
(33, 'nnn', 'fffqf', 'fff', 'fff'),
(34, 'nnnn', 'nn', 'nnn', 'nnn'),
(35, 'ssaa', 'sss', 'sss', 'sss'),
(36, 'hi ', 'fff', 'fff', 'fff'),
(37, 'hh', 'hh', 'hh', 'hh');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `crud`
--
ALTER TABLE `crud`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `crud`
--
ALTER TABLE `crud`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=38;COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What values do you enter there?

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Use [prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: im not concerned about attacks, its for school assignment,

Comment: There's no reason why you should learn it the wrong way when you can learn it the right way.

Comment: Also, your full error message is a lot more helpful, it'll say where the error is *near*. Without that, we can only guess where it's going wrong. I'm *guessing* that by using a prepared statement, your error goes away.

Comment: Why are we coding in a pattern that is vulnerable to SQL Injection? Why should industry professionals spend their time debugging code in a broken pattern, when a proper pattern is available? As an excuse, the "it's for a school assignment" just doesn't cut it. Schools promoting evil coding patterns are doing its students a disservice.  (Also, the `or die` following the assignment of value to a string variable `$sql` doesn't make sense. If the string assignment fails, mysqli->error isn't going to provide any useful info.)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example using your SQL. This takes no more time to code than what you started with.

```
<?php    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db   = 'test';
    $user = 'admin';
    $pass = 'howtoforge';

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    try{
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $name = 'NameF'; 
    $last = 'O\'Conner';
    $email = 'none@none.com';
    $birthday = '12/01/9999';
    $id = '1';

    try{
    $stmt = $con->prepare('
     UPDATE
        crud 
     SET
        name     = ?, 
        last     = ?, 
        email    = ?, 
        birthday = ?
     WHERE 
        id = ?;
    ');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $name, $last, $email, $birthday, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't catch the exception just to echo it out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape your post inputs as some of the inputs might contain illegal characters which is causing the MySQL error. Do it this way:
`$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['id']);` and the error will be gone.

As others have mentioned, however, you shouldn't use input from user without validation and sanitization to avoid SQL injection attack or just use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/) the string is not safe!

Comment: I know it's not and others have pointed that out too to the author. My answer is to solve the current problem stated, and I added caveats.

Comment: I understand that you want to answer these questions, but at what point do we stop supporting laziness. The poster does not care or know about prepared statements because the teacher does not care or know. So now we have how many programmers entering the work force. Who don't know how may problems they are going to cause.

Comment: Answering someone's question while showing them a better way is the right thing to do, I think. Anyone seeing the answer also sees the part where it's stated that input shouldn't be used directly, as well as the better way to go about it.